# value error in my code (python 3.0) 'chr() arg not in range'

Tags: python, string

I have to take in a string and an integer value and check if the string is lowercase or uppercase, and based on that I have to increment it by number `k`. for eg if `k=4` and string is `'ABab'` it should give the output `'EFef'`.

This is my code only for checking lowercase. Unfortunately is giving `ValueError`.

```
s=input()
k=int(input())
l=[]
for i in s:
    if i.islower():
        if 97>=(ord(i)+k)<=122:
            l.append(chr(ord(i)+k))
    else:
        k=k-122
        if 97>=(ord(i)+k)<=122:
            l.append((chr(ord(i)+k)))
            break
        else:
            continue
print(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

The traceback shows where the error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rob/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    l.append((chr(ord(i)+k)))
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)
```

You are passing an argument to `chr` that is not within the allowed range. As described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html):

> The valid range for the argument is from 0 through 1,114,111 (0x10FFFF
>   in base 16). ValueError will be raised if i is outside that range.

This is because you have changed the value of k to (probably) be a large negative number:

```
k=k-122
```

So the result of `ord(i)+k` is also often negative. Negative numbers are not in the allowed range, so the call to `chr` fails.

There are lots of other problems with your code, and I don't think you'd learn much if I just wrote "my solution" to the problem. Another thing you might want to look at to begin with is that:

```
if 97>=(ord(i)+k)<=122:
```

doesn't do what you want, you probably want:

```
if 97<=(ord(i)+k)<=122:
```

Comment: Please note that the range "0-255" is a Python 2 thing only - nowadays most people use Python 3, and CHR and ORD give results in unicode code points.

That said, the OP is likely using Python 2, which should be noted in the answer, them.

Comment: @jsbueno Thanks, good catch, I've updated my answer for Python 3. I'm sure OP is using Python 3 because of the `print(l)` at the end of the question.

Comment: @jsbueno I think it's more accurate to say that most people *learning Python* are using Python 3 (or should be, anyway). The installed base of Python 2 code is still quite large (though probably larger than it *should* be, with [Python 2 support coming to an end](https://pythonclock.org)).